# audio on/off con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo los siguientes codigos:

```css
#headset {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/bMKXrR/Zeichenfl_che_2_gr_n.png");
   
}

#headset:hover {
    background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/gDzXrR/Zeichenfl_che_4.png");
}
```

```html
  <div id="headset"></div>

<audio autoplay loop id="music-ebene2-background">
    <source src="https://d1490khl9dq1ow.cloudfront.net/music/mp3preview/fun-guitar-and-ukulele-full_fk4ltN4O.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Y necesito una función que haga que cuando pulso, se ponga la música en off o en on. La cuestión es que trabajo en un doc. completo .js por que es un proyecto muuuuy grande y necesito que a este se le puedan añadir mas adelante mas sonidos que se corten a la vez.

Yo he encontrado esto;

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("video1");
vid.muted = true;
```

Creo que eso me vale, pero no se como llevarlo a cabo. ¿Alguien me podría echar una mano?

Gracias

***Editado.***

Bueno, lo he logrado con paciencia luego de un hora...ahora mi problema es añadirle un evento oneclick que haga que cuando pulso pause cambie la imagen y cuando pulso otravez vuelva a cambiar. Lo que tengo hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

```js
var audio = document.getElementById('music-ebene2-background');

document.getElementById('headset').addEventListener('click', function (e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    audio.muted = !audio.muted;
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```css
#headset {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/bMKXrR/Zeichenfl_che_2_gr_n.png");
   
}

#headset:hover {
    background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/gDzXrR/Zeichenfl_che_4.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="headset"></div>

<audio autoplay loop id="music-ebene2-background">
    <source src="https://d1490khl9dq1ow.cloudfront.net/music/mp3preview/fun-guitar-and-ukulele-full_fk4ltN4O.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

De momento tengo ese hover, pero eso se va y quiero usar el link de hover en el evento oneclick

Comment: Sólo tienes que ejecutar esas líneas cuando se hace click en la imagen que quieras,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para generar esa especie de `switch` que pides en tu imagen, yo haría lo siguiente:

```js
var audio = document.getElementById('music-ebene2-background');

document.getElementById('headset').addEventListener('click', function (e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    audio.muted = !audio.muted;

    if(audio.muted){
        document.getElementById('headset').setAttribute('class', 'active_headset');
    }else{
        document.getElementById('headset').removeAttribute("class");
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```css
#headset {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/bMKXrR/Zeichenfl_che_2_gr_n.png");
   
}

.active_headset{
    background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/gDzXrR/Zeichenfl_che_4.png") !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="headset"></div>

<audio autoplay loop id="music-ebene2-background">
    <source src="https://d1490khl9dq1ow.cloudfront.net/music/mp3preview/fun-guitar-and-ukulele-full_fk4ltN4O.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Si!, perfecto, dios me has aliviado el dolor de cabeza........Gracias, de verdad....y lo mejo es que entiendo el codigo.

Comment: Ahora en caso de que tenga dos audios, solo tengo que y añadir esto al script no?  var audio = document.getElementById('music-ebene2-background');
        document.getElementById(''audio2);

Comment: En caso que tengas mas audios debes manejar un parámetro this en la función para que la imagen que tenga el cambio sea a la que le acabas de dar click y se ignoren las otras, a no ser que uses funciones y clases diferentes para cada uno

Comment: Nono, basicamente, lo que quiero es que cuando se reproduzcan dos o mas audios a la vez, se puedan pausar todos de un golpe.

Comment: Ah entonces si, capturas los audios y les das mute :)